# How to find an object in an existing array of arrays

Tags: php, arrays

I am not sure if the title is understandable with my case here, since I am still considered noob in PHP.

Here is my code

```
// An object has property e.g. (ID, Name, Status)
// This function returns an array of object.
function getObjects ($pid) { //return objects }

$pids = { 2, 23, 41, 45, 56, 91, 105, 107, 210 };

$myArr = array();

foreach ($pids as $pid)
{
  $myObjects = getObjects($pid);

  if (count($myObjects) > 0)
  {
    array_push($myArr, $myObjects);
  }
}

if ( count($myArr) > 0 )
{
  $result = "You have " . count($myArr) . " pending object";
}
```

So, inside ***$myArr*** there are collections of ***$myObjects*** array, and each ***$myObjects*** array contains ***$myObject***.

The problem is, in ***$myArr***, I don't want to have any similar ***$myObject*** (Let's say no multiple same IDs).

Currently, the ***$result*** is..

> You have 4 pending object

Currently in my real application, with those ***$pids***, ***$myArr*** contains with ***4 of $myObjects*** and each of these ***$myObjects*** contain ***only 1 of $myObject*** that has the same **IDs**.

Since they have similarities on their **IDs**, I wish my ***$result*** to be

> You have 1 pending object

I am sorry for the bad explaination, I hope I made myself quite clear this far.

**EDIT**

```
    $arrDraftLoadplans        = array();
    $arrDraftPickslips        = array();
    $arrDraftReplenishments   = array();
    $arrUncompletedWriteoffs  = array();
    $arrUncompletedASNs       = array();
    $arrDraftReplenishment    = array();

    $totalError = 0;
    $resultFormat = "</br><a href='%s'>%d %s</a>";

    $draftTRNs                = PutawayPeer::getPutawaysByProductIdAndStatus(null, Putaway::STATUS_DRAFT);
    if ( count ($draftTRNs) > 0 )
    {
      $result .= sprintf ($resultFormat, "../warehouseReturns/putawayList?principal_id=-1&refresh=Refresh", count ($draftTRNs), "Unconfirmed Putaway(s)");
      $totalError++;
    }

    foreach ($productIds as $pid)
    {
      $draftLoadplans       = LoadPlanPeer::getLoadplansByProductIdAndStatus($pid);
      if (count($draftLoadplans) > 0)
      {
        array_push($arrDraftLoadplans, $draftLoadplans);
      }

      $draftPickslips       = PickSlipPeer::getPickslipsByProductIdAndPicklistStatus($pid);
      if (count($draftPickslips) > 0)
      {
        array_push($arrDraftPickslips, $draftPickslips);
      }

      $draftReplenishments  = ReplenishmentPeer::getReplenishmentsByProductIdAndStatus($pid);
      if (count($draftReplenishments) > 0)
      {
        array_push($arrDraftReplenishments, $draftReplenishments);
      }

      $uncompletedWriteoffs = WriteOffPickslipPeer::getUnconfirmedWriteOffPickslipsByProductId($pid);
      if (count($uncompletedWriteoffs) > 0)
      {
        array_push($arrUncompletedWriteoffs, $uncompletedWriteoffs);
      }

      $uncompletedASNs      = AdvanceShippingNoticePeer::getAdvanceShippingNoticesByProductIdAndBetweenStatus($pid);
      if (count($uncompletedASNs) > 0)
      {
        array_push($arrUncompletedASNs, $uncompletedASNs);
      }
    }


    if (count($arrDraftLoadplans) > 0)
    {
      $result .= sprintf ($resultFormat, "../warehouseOutbound/outPickrelease", count ($arrDraftLoadplans), "Pending Loadplan(s)");
      $totalError++;
    }

    if (count($arrDraftPickslips) > 0)
    {
      $result .= sprintf ($resultFormat, "../warehouseOutbound/outPicking", count ($arrDraftPickslips), "Pending Pickslip(s)");
      $totalError++;
    }

    if (count($arrDraftReplenishment) > 0)
    {
      $result .= sprintf ($resultFormat, "../inventoryStockReplenishment/replenishmentList", count ($arrDraftReplenishment), "Pending Replenishment(s)");
      $totalError++;
    }

    if (count($arrUncompletedWriteoffs) > 0)
    {
      $result .= sprintf ($resultFormat, "../warehouseReturns/writeOffPickslipList", count ($arrUncompletedWriteoffs), "Pending Write-Off(s)");
      $totalError++;
    }

    if (count($arrUncompletedASNs) > 0)
    {
      $result .= sprintf ($resultFormat, "#", count ($arrUncompletedASNs), "Pending ASN(s)");
      $totalError++;
    }
```

Comment: Post original array or just improve your question with better example which have some relevance along with your current code

Comment: Ah, could you edit the `//return objects }` part :) It comments out the last `}` so to me it looks like there's a function called  `getObjects` which gets called endlessly and would end in too much iteration... Think most people trying to help will get that when  looking at your code :D

Comment: @Uchiha I added the original codes..

Comment: @HansWassink there are at least 5 or more functions to that, to make it simpler I put it like that..

Comment: And I am very much aware that this can be approached by nested foreach and if conditions, but I am hoping for different approach.

Comment: Ah, I just wrote you an easy solution using just that :D Still want me to post it?

Comment: @HansWassink You mean by editing those functions? I still don't quite get what you mean

Comment: Ill add my code as an answer... It's by far the easiest option. You can also `array_map` / `array_unique` your array afterwards, but that only works if the objects are exactly the same, not just the id's.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This helps you end up with an array filled with only unique objects.

```
<?php 
// An object has property e.g. (ID, Name, Status)
// This function returns an array of object.
function getObjects($pid) {
    //return objects     
}

$pids = array(2, 23, 41, 45, 56, 91, 105, 107, 210);

$myArr = array();
$usedIds = array();

foreach ($pids as $pid) {
    $myObjects = getObjects($pid);

    if (count($myObjects) > 0) {
        foreach($myObjects as $myObj){
            if(!in_array($myObj->ID, $usedIds)){
                $usedIds = $myObj->ID;
                $myArr[] = $myObj;
            }
        }
    }
}

if (count($myArr) > 0) {
    $result = "You have " . count($myArr) . " pending object(s)";
}
```

Comment: Oh, you mean to us $myArr to store $myObject instead of $myObjects? That should be an option, but I'd have to declare more new variables and I am afraid this kind of code is hard to maintain with other developers.. But thanks, I'll try this and let u know soon.

Comment: Thanks hans, atm I can't find another approach better than nested foreach.

Answer (score 1):

So are those **$myObjects** different objects with potentially the same ID(s), or potentially the same objects with same ID(s) ?

If you just want to remove duplicates you can for example flatten you array up (make it one dimensional), and then remove duplicates.

```
// flatten array
$flattenedArray = array_reduce($myArr, 'array_merge', array());
// remove duplicates
$myNewArr = array_unique($flattenedArray);
```

Though I haven't tested that, but it should work in the described case.

Comment: They are the same object. Yes, I want to remove duplicates of value inside of an array of arrays. I'll try this as well. Thanks for ur answer

Comment: Also, in you MyObject class you can implement the __toString() method that would return the ID, that way the above code is valid and array_unique would consider 2 objects the same if they have the same ID (although there are cleaner ways to achieve that). Just throwing this in here for the future :)

Comment: Wow, actually array_unique($myArr) does the trick. That's pretty simple and magic method actually. It returns only 1 array instead of 4. I am kinda experimenting if there's any downside for this. TYVM

Comment: Nope, sorry its my bad... I've simulated array_unique or/and array_reduce as ur method, and it seems like its not the answer im looking for..  Thanks anyway :)